# How to use customEnhancer for plugin in TYPO3 version 9

Tags: router, typo3-extensions, realurl, typo3-9.x

**My url is**

backPid=5&tx_viextendednews_newsblog%5Baction%5D=show&tx_viextendednews_newsblog%5Bcontroller%5D=Extendednews&tx_viextendednews_newsblog%5Bextendednews%5D=1

**and I want to make it**

**/news-detail/newstitle/?backpid=5**

**I wrote in my ext_local.conf file**
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['routing']['CustomPlugin'] = \VrisiniInfotechLLP\ViExtendednews\Routing\CustomEnhancer::class;

**And my customenhancer is**

```
class CustomEnhancer extends AbstractEnhancer implements RoutingEnhancerInterface, ResultingInterface
{
  /**
  * @var array
  */
  protected $configuration;

  /**
  * @var string
  */
  protected $namespace;
  public function __construct(array $configuration)
 {
    $this->configuration = $configuration;
    $this->namespace = $this->configuration['namespace'] ?? '';
 }
}
```

My config.yaml path is
/siteroot/typo3conf/sites/foldername/config.yaml

```
routeEnhancers:
NewsPlugin:
type: Extbase
limitToPages: [13]
extension: Extendednews
plugin: newsblog
routes:
  - { routePath: '/detail/{news_title}', _controller:   'Extendednews::show', _arguments: {'news_title': 'news'} }
defaultController: 'Extendednews::show'
aspects:
  news_title:
    type: PersistedAliasMapper
    tableName: 'tx_news_domain_model_news'
    routeFieldName: 'path_segment'
    routeValuePrefix: '/'
```

**How Can I understand that this file is working internally?**
**Now Mys question is what I should write in this file so that I can get the desired url?**

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code for an own routing aspect. 
Use DebuggerUtility::var_dump($value) to see what happens in this Aspect class:

```
    <?php
    namespace VENDOR\MyExtension\Routing\Aspect;

    use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Aspect\StaticMappableAspectInterface;
    use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Site\SiteLanguageAwareTrait;
    use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility;

    class IdentifierValueMapper implements StaticMappableAspectInterface
    {
        use SiteLanguageAwareTrait;

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function generate(string $value): ?string
        {
            return $value !== false ? (string)$value : null;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function resolve(string $value): ?string
        {
            return isset($value) ? (string)$value : null;
        }
    }
```

config.yaml

```
    defaults:
      identifierPlaceholder: ''
    requirements:
      identifierPlaceholder: '^[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}$'
    aspects:
      identifierPlaceholder:
        type: IdentifierValueMapper
```

localconf.php

```
    // Custom Routing Aspects Mapper
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['routing']['aspects']['IdentifierValueMapper'] = \VENDOR\MyExtension\Routing\Aspect\IdentifierValueMapper::class;
```

Comment: what is the path of your config.yaml?

Comment: the path is /typo3conf/sites/my-site-configuration/config.yaml   https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.2/Feature-84581-SiteHandling.html